# ECS Task Not Running - AWS Cognito

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm trying to use JavaScript to run a task in ECS Fargate. AWS suggested to use Cognito Identity Credentials. When I pass in IdentityPoolId shown in:

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
aws.config.credentials = new aws.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId: <identity-pool-id>
})
```

I get a message in the console like:

```
Uncaught (in promise) AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::<accountid>:assumed-role/Cognito_<appname>Unauth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: ecs:RunTask on resource: arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:<accountid>:task-definition/<image-name>:<version> because no session policy allows the ecs:RunTask action
```

How do you resolve this issue. I'm looking at the activity in ECS and I see that the Unauth role did get assumed and it accessed ECS. It's just that the `runTask` doesn't work. Can someone provide example working code to solve this?

Comment: "AWS suggested to use Cognito Identity Credentials" -> Where does it say that? Is your JS code private or are you running this on the client-side?

Comment: Here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-browser-credentials-cognito.html says that the best way for browser to fetch AWS credentials on the Javascript side is to use Cognito Identity credentails. This code is being run on the frontend. Also, by any chance, do you know if there is an easy way to sync firebase authenticated user data to cognito user pool

Comment: Resolved this doubt. I didn't end up using Cognito for this. I instead let the ECS task creation happen in the backend rather than frontend :) Boto3 with ecs fargate is so much easier to use than Cognito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't end up going the Cognito route. It's just that AWS Cognito seems super unintuitive and from an engineering standpoint, it would make sense that the backend should be handling ECS stuff for my use case. Plus, ECS with boto 3 is so much easier to use impo